# Google Charts - Large / Huge data

Tags: php, performance, google-visualization

I am trying to see if I can display million of points on the line chart; but struggling to effectively display more then 5k points.

I was looking to generate json file using example below: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example but the json file with 2 million points has a size of about 20MB which is massive.

Is their any tricks on displaying large sets?

Comment: recommend drawing points in batches, wait for the `'ready'` event, then add more data and draw, wait for the `'ready'` event, add more, etc. -- this will allow the chart to start providing feedback, instead of waiting until all is finished...

Comment: ok and how much data might you be able to handle like that?

Comment: the only limit would be on the client and the amount of memory it can use before becoming unresponsive...

Comment: Is their a snippet? I am worried that google charts is not the right way forward to display large sets of data; i would want my chart to show upto 20 million points, and given that json file for 20 mil might be around 200MB it might not be a feasible solution?

Comment: probably not feasible, regardless of charting solution...

Comment: the only solution that i can see is displaying no more then 100k points on the graph; i think 100k points is ok number of points to show. and when user zooms in / out or slides left or right; we would load new data; not sure if google charts sends queries  to the data sources with info about the dates between which we should get the data?

Comment: user3402600, did you find any solution for charting your massive data? In my application, I need to draw charts for millions of records and I'm not sure if Google Visualization is the best option for me

Comment: As WhiteHat mentioned above - you cant display a large set of data on a single screen due to hardware limitations on the end-users PC. You can, however, initially display a small set of data and then allow the end-user to scroll backwards and forwards on the graph; on each scroll you would load a new set of data via AJAX. I have solved this problem by having two buttons to load next/prev set of data and the slick scroll solution is my next step. Let me know if you have any questions.